# periodical ping [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails so I wonder if there is something like crontab that does some tasks periodically. Basically I need to ping a url of a entity but each entity in different interval (entity1 each 600ms, entity2 each 500ms ...). Is there anything in ruby that does this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options, depending on what your needs are.

- [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)
- [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job)
- [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) (likely overkill)

You can also just use `cron` and `rails runner`; just depends.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I need to dynamically add/remove these periodical jobs according to entities (eg. services) they belong. I have multiple services each with multiple endpoints. I have to ping each endpoint of the service in an interval that belongs to the service (eg. 500ms). This "pinging" starts when the service is registered and ends when the service is deleted from a system. Is it possible to implement this in gems you presented, because as I see there is only fixed schedule of jobs.

Comment: @MrBlack I'm not sure. But to be honest, I'm not sure I'd do this inside the app, either... Your timing needs are pretty aggressive, especially if you have a lot of endpoints. I'd consider running some tests, maybe a single job should just spin off each entity's ping, or...? Consider unaccepting the answer and wait for some more-appropriate input, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at using sidekiq + https://github.com/musicglue/sidekiq-isochronal

You can create a worker for each entity and define a schedule for each one.